# Chrome Extension: How to log something from included JS script file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script in my Chrome Extension included in the `<script src="myscript.js">` mode. How can I write to the console from myscript.js?

A code snippet from myscript.js:

```
try {
      fields = normalizeFields(JSON.parse(data).fields);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(data, e);

      console.log(data);
      console.log(e);
      return alert('Unable to parse response from server, try again.');
    }
```

The alert is firing, but the `console.log(data)` isn't. The background page does show the error, but it's a bit cryptic and seeing all the data would make debugging significantly easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the filter in the developer console set to show "all" ?

Comment: @epascarello Yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/google-chrome-firefox-do-not-see-extension-output-in-console)